# JHipster - Single Page Application - OAuth2 / OIDC and access token location

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, single-page-application, jhipster, openid-connect

Note that I'm quite new with OAuth2 and OpenID Connect so I may be a little bit confused. AFAIK, the recommanded authentication flow with OAuth2 in 2021 is **Authorization Code Flow**. I have already read the [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).

I have initialized a project using JHipster (v6.10.5, not the v7) with this configuration:

- Which *type* of application would you like to create? **Monolithic application** (recommended for simple projects)
- Which *type* of authentication would you like to use? **OAuth 2.0 / OIDC Authentication (stateful, works with Keycloak and Okta)**
- Which *Framework* would you like to use for the client? **React** (i.e. a SPA application)

I'm wondering **why is the JHipster's implementation stateful?** (i.e. using HTTP session cookie *JSESSIONID* ; access token and refresh token are stored *on the backend-side* and ****NOT*** on the browser-side*).

**Why don't they make the browser acting as an OAuth 2.0 client to perform the authentication and storing the access token and the refresh token *on the browser-side***?

I don't find any explanation on the [JHispter security page](https://www.jhipster.tech/security/).

Beside, [this blog](https://medium.com/@robert.broeckelmann/securely-using-the-oidc-authorization-code-flow-and-a-public-client-with-single-page-applications-55e0a648ab3a) mentions a schema that explains the OIDC Authorization Code Flow with a Public Client / SPA.

Comment: Do also see https://leastprivilege.com/2020/03/31/spas-are-dead/

Comment: We implemented it this way because it's the most secure, with the OAuth flow happening on the backend (back channel) rather than the front channel (in your browser). If we changed to the front channel, we'd have to implement OIDC in each client framework, and it'd be less secure because access tokens would be stored on the client. Also, JWTs suck as session tokens. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/08/17/why-jwts-suck-as-session-tokens

Answer (score 0):

To complete Matt Raible comment, from [OAuth 2.0 for Browser-Based Apps - draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-07 and §6.1.  Browser-Based Apps that Can Share Data with the Resource Server](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-07#section-6.1):

> [...]
>
> An additional concern with handling access tokens in a browser is that as of the date of this publication, **there is *no secure storage mechanism* where JavaScript code can keep the access token to be later used in an API request**.  Using an OAuth flow results in the JavaScript code getting an access token, needing to store it somewhere, and then retrieve it to make an API request.
>
> Instead, a more secure design is to **use an HTTP-only cookie** between the JavaScript application and API **so that the JavaScript code can't access the cookie value itself**.  Additionally, the SameSite cookie attribute can be used to prevent CSRF attacks, or alternatively, the application and API could be written to use anti-CSRF tokens.
>
> [...]

However, I think the use of HTTP-session and OAuth2 token on the backend-side may complexify the management/implementation of some issues as we have to handle different timeouts:

- idle timeout for HTTP session between the browser and the backend
- expiration timeout or maximum lifetime expiration for the refresh token that is stored on the backend side
- ...

I'm now wondering how to provide a user-friendly experience, when some borderline cases happen. E.g: when the refresh token has expired on the backend-side but the end-user is still connected as the HTTP session between the browser and the backend is still valid.